# How to get systeminfo locale - Locale.getDefault()

Tags: java, windows, java-6

Currently my System Locale is `en-UK`, it used to be `en-US` (I've restarted my computer for this change to be in effect)

When I print `Locale.getDefault().getCountry().toString()` I still get US though.

In the API it states:

> getDefault()
>
> Gets the current value of the default locale for this
> instance of the Java Virtual Machine.

Maybe the JVM locale is not related to the system locale? If so, how do I get the system locale on Windows?

**Edits:**

- after researching the other questions about this, I found it useful to say that I'm dealing with Java 6.
- I've just found that on my OS (Windows 7) the System locale change is not reflected in Java, but the Control Panel > Region and Language > Formats change is reflected.
- I've overlooked something, in production code the osgi.nl config attribute is set, changing what Locale.getDefault would return otherwise

Comment: Did you maybe add `-Duser.language` when running Java?

Comment: No, Java was launched without arguments.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks for the comment. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: So based on your second edit, now it is working?

Comment: Well, the underlying problem, that the System Locale is not adequately fetched by a JVM without arguments on Windows 7 still remains. Despite that, I no longer have a problem with it, because I now understand what needs to be changed to be reflected in the JVM Locale. Should I close the question?

Comment: Ugh, it seems like not all Windows versions react the same. @RealSkeptic do you maybe know of any better way of universally checking for Locale for Windows?

Comment: TBH Windows is not my strong side, but have you checked and followed [the instructions by Oracle](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml)?

Comment: Yes, I have. I need to give you an update soon, because I've discovered in a different part of the code that Locale.setDefault was improperly used...will confirm soon

Comment: @RealSkeptic I realized that in the production environment there were actually arguments being set, such as osgi.nl ... There was a difference between debugging environment and production. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized in production an argument WAS being set that altered the Locale.getDefault() return value. This was difficult to check/prove.

My solution was that the user.country and user.language were not changed and reflected the actual Locale.

```
Locale locale = new Locale(System.getProperty("user.language"),System.getProperty("user.country"));
Locale.setDefault(locale);
//this will do the trick for me
```

Big thanks to everyone who answered and commented.

Answer (score 3):

Your JVM locale and System locale can indeed possibly be different.
When the JVM is first loaded it assigns its locale to be the same as the system's locale unless you specified otherwise on the command line (not all implementations let you do this).
You can see what the value of this JVM locale is from `Locale.getDefault()`.

In case you want to change that you can: `Locale.setDefault("<preferred_locale>")` [read more about it here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

The system locale setting depends on the OS that you are using. I don't know much about Windows but, you can see what the values are from `System.getEnv()`. It returns a `Map<String, String>` of all environment properties and you can look for something like LANG or GDM_LANG, etc.

Comment: Do you imply, that on second launch Java uses persisted language name set on the first one? Why other options are not persisted then?

Comment: The documentation clearly says that getDefault() gets the "current value of the default locale for this instance of the JVM".  I don't think it persists the locale.

Comment: Some background on Java using the user locale can be found here: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sherman/4958170.html I think in your case you should check the "non unicode" setting. It might influence the country variant (although not documented in mentioned link).

Comment: Thanks for the System.getenv() tip. This lead me to checking out the content of System.getProperties() and I realized what was the problem, an argument was being set in production, by a separate part of the framework

Answer (score 1):

The country variant is taken from the "Non-Unicode" settings in the extended dialog of Windows locale.

Answer (score 1):

There was is bug in Sun JDK 6u27+ and JDK 7, [BugId 7073906](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7073906):

> The Locale returned from Locale.getDefault() is en_US when it shoud be en_GB.

I think this is what is biting you here :)